# http GET file requests with strange query strings

Tags: apache, http, query-string

I was inspecting one web page with Flash application and found out network activity (in chrome developer tools) which was was requesting different files with GET requests and query parameter strings like that "0.6677141911350190.108787443954498" (numbers differ from each other). Request looks like this:
        `http://domain.com/something-else/filename.txt?0.3556782724335790.292622108012438`
Is this some custom http request which is handled by unknown server logic or can it be something standard? What is the meaning of these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like cache busting technique. Sometimes developers append random parameters to filenames to prevent caching. But it can be a specific logic too.